# How to create html page in dupal 7

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to develop a  web app with Drupal 7. I would like to create my own html pages and include them in my drupal. I have seen that it is possible with hook_menu API like in this example given in drupal Example module (see below). This method is cool when you want to create a page "Hello World Technology" but how do I do if I want to include more complex html pages? Do I have to put my 500-lines html code in the associative array '#markup' and escape all " or ' characters? I will never finish my web app at this rate...

Can you guys please help me or advice me?

Thanx a lot

```
function page_example_menu() {

  // This is the minimum information you can provide for a menu item. This menu
  // item will be created in the default menu, usually Navigation.
  $items['examples/page_example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Page Example',
    'page callback' => 'page_example_description',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  );

  $items['examples/page_example/simple'] = array(
    'title' => 'Simple - no arguments',
    'page callback' => 'page_example_simple',
    'access arguments' => array('access simple page'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function page_example_description() {
  return array(
    '#markup' =>
    t('<p>The page_example provides two pages, "simple" and "arguments".</p><p>The <a href="@simple_link">simple page</a> just returns a renderable array for display.</p><p>The <a href="@arguments_link">arguments page</a> takes two arguments and displays them, as in @arguments_link</p>',
      array(
        '@simple_link' => url('examples/page_example/simple', array('absolute' => TRUE)),
        '@arguments_link' => url('examples/page_example/arguments/23/56', array('absolute' => TRUE)),
      )
    ),
  );
}

function page_example_simple() {
  return array('#markup' => '<p>' . t('Simple page: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.') . '</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that Drupal is a Content Management System and what you are trying to achieve is the core of what Drupal does.

To create your own HTML pages:

Navigate to /node/add
Select a plain page (You can even create your own content types later).
Wack all your HTML in the body, you can select the input filter, go to source mode if you want, you may want to look at including CKEditor or some sort of WYSIWYG perhaps, which is quite common with Drupal.

In this same screen you can set the URL.

No need to create menu hooks and put markup in code for basic HTML pages, this is what the CMS is for!

Comment: Hi klidifia, thanx for your update. Actually what I need to do is a webapp with php, some part are pure static html but some other part are dynamic, can I do that with the method you gave me? Thank you in advance.